# How can I dissolve carbon using generally available substances?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, carbon-family

I am asking this question out of despair: my wife burned to death crèpes dough into our induction stove.

[image]

I tried all usual products (the ones to clean the stove, vinegar, then sodium bicarbonate left for some time, gentle mechanical prying, ...) but it is stuck.

**Is there a way to dissolve carbon (burned organic substance) using a reasonably available substance?** (say, HClO3 would be doable,  H2SbF6 or C2N14 - not that much). For the sake of the exercise, let's assume that it would be handled by a physicist.

Comment: Unfortunately, this may require suitable abrasives, a high speed rotary tool and lots of elbow grease and time. Good luck!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community: well, I am not sire what is not clear: I have burned organic stuff on an induction stove and I would like to use a substance that is generally available to the public to dissolve it. What exact extra information are you looking for, exactly? (the answer from Maurice is the kind I was looking for)

Comment: Please let us know if something actually works and also please edit to post the “after” photo!

Comment: From the brown color, your stain is still not pure carbon (perhaps polymerized fats/oils and charred sugar). There are chemical ways to oxidize organic matter from glass but not applicable domestic objects. The lye method (NaOH) is perhaps still your savior as suggested in the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to dissolve a black deposit on glass is to use a concentrated solution of $\ce{NaOH}$, about half water - half $\ce{NaOH}$. But take care ! This dissolution is highly exothermic. Try to prepare not more than a couple of milliliters of it in a test glass tube. The test tube will get hot during the mixing and dissolution operation. And take care ! This solution should not touch your skin, as it will soon destroy it. Be ready to intervene with sodium bicarbonate : this powder  destroys $\ce{NaOH}$.

A couple of milliliters of this $\ce{NsOH}$ solution is enough for your cleaning purposes. Have one or two drops of it on the burned organic spot. Rub with some blotting paper or toilet paper to remove the spot. Don't wait ! The dark stuff will quickly be absorbed by the paper. But take care, not to touch the stuff with your fingers. Rub with new clean paper, and then rinse several times with water each time with a new piece of toilet paper. I have used this process many times on the window of my oven, and it has always worked perfectly.

Last advice. Don't wait cleaning the clean glass surface. If you forget to clean the glass surface quickly, the $\ce{NaOH}$ solution will slowly corrode the glas itself. And take care to avoid contact with aluminum pieces. NaOH destroys aluminum rather quickly.

In case of an accidental contact with $\ce{NaOH}$, go for a shower and wash a long time, until no soap feeling are felt any more on the $\ce{NaOH}$ spot.

Comment: I would suggest that the OP use some PPE, like eye protection and rubber gloves, and use a scrap piece of cloth or paper towel: toilet paper shreds easily, by its design, when wet.

Comment: I agree with everything except the "Don't wait" part. You'd probably have to wait for some time, and even then I wouldn't be too optimistic.

Comment: There is a commercially available solution of KOH in polyethylene glycol/water gel. In the UK this is marketed as Ovenmate, this may be useful

Comment: @Ed V and Ivan Neretin. I repeat. I have done it several times at home and also in a chalet in the mountain. I always worked properly and quickly. Of course, gloves are an efficient protection. I remember that once I thought it was useful to wait half an hour or so before cleaning it. Now the window is frosted.

Comment: @ Waylander. Thank you for the information about the commercial gel. The trouble is that you are obliged to buy a whole bottle. And you only need one or two milliliters.

Comment: @EdV: yes of course. This is what I meant by the fact that this will be done by a physicist - I did a lot of experiments and safety is important and a given. But it is always good to remind that, thanks.

Comment: @Maurice It keeps. Good for cleaning pyrex, stainless steel and cast iron pans too.

Comment: Unfortunately, the stains did not bulge. I bought yesterday NaOH, it came as a powder (small crystals) and I tried a 1:1 dilution (indeed, it was noticeably exothermic) and then a stringer one but there was not a single black particle on the towel. Thank you for the idea, though, it may be useful in another case.